# FFmpeg in Python File already exists error

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, ffmpeg, ffmpy

I'm working on a project using python(3.6) and Django(2.0) in which i'm converting a video to mp4 if it's in any other formate.

Here's my code:

**from views.py:**

```
def generate_thumbnail(filename, thumb_name):
    print('func called')
    print(filename)
    video_input_path = os.path.join(filename)
    img_output_path = os.path.join(thumb_name)
    subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', '-i', video_input_path, '-ss', '00:00:00.000', 'vframes', '1', img_output_path])


def convert_to_mp4(video_name, only_name):
    os.popen(
        "ffmpeg -i '{input}' -ac 2 -b:v 2000k -c:a aac -c:v libx264 -b:a 160k -vprofile high -bf 0 -strict experimental -f mp4 '{output}.mp4'".format(
            input=video_name, output=only_name))
    return True


def perform_upload(video, thumbnail):
    print('vdieo name is: {}'.format(video))
    servise = discovery.build('storage', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
    bucket_name = 'test_bucket004'
    print('Uploading the video...')
    media = MediaFileUpload(video, chunksize=4149304, mimetype='video/mp4',
                            resumable=True)
    req = servise.objects().insert(
        bucket=bucket_name,
        name=str(video),
        media_body=media,
        body={"cacheControl": "public,max-age=31536000"},
        predefinedAcl='publicRead'
    )
    resp = None
    while resp is None:
        status, resp = req.next_chunk()
    print(resp)
    video_url = 'http://storage.googleapis.com/' + bucket_name + '/' + str(video)

    print('Uploading your thumbnail...')
    media = MediaFileUpload(thumbnail, chunksize=4149304, mimetype='image/jpeg',
                            resumable=True)
    req = servise.objects().insert(
        bucket=bucket_name,
        name=str(thumbnail),
        media_body=media,
        body={"cacheControl": "public,max-age=31536000"},
        predefinedAcl='publicRead'
    )
    resp = None
    while resp is None:
        status, resp = req.next_chunk()
    print(resp)
    thumb_url = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/' + bucket_name + '/' + str(thumbnail)

    return video_url, thumb_url


class VideoConverter(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponse('Get request', status=200)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = VideoConverterSerializer(data=self.request.data)
        validation = serializer.is_valid()
        print(serializer.errors)
        if validation is True:
            url = request.POST.get('video_url')
            filename = url.split('/')
            filename = filename[-1]
            print(filename)
            ext = filename.split('.')
            print(ext[-1])
            only_name = ext[0]
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename)
            generate_thumbnail(filename, only_name + '_thumbnail.jpg')
            if ext == 'mp4':
                videourl, thumb_url = perform_upload(filename, only_name + '_thumbnail.jpg')
            else:
                conversion = convert_to_mp4(filename, only_name)
                if conversion is True:
                    videourl, thumb_url = perform_upload(only_name + '.mp4', only_name + '_thumbnail.jpg')

            return HttpResponse('Video url is: {}\n \nThumbnail url is: {}'.format(videourl, thumb_url))
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Not a valid request')
```

But when I pass it a video of Mp4 format it returns an error in the IDE console like this:

> ffmpeg version 4.0.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
>     built with Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.10.43.1)
>     configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.0.2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --enable-videotoolbox --disable-lzma
>     libavutil      56. 14.100 / 56. 14.100
>     libavcodec     58. 18.100 / 58. 18.100
>     libavformat    58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
>     libavdevice    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
>     libavfilter     7. 16.100 /  7. 16.100
>     libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
>     libswscale      5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
>     libswresample   3.  1.100 /  3.  1.100
>     libpostproc    55.  1.100 / 55.  1.100
>   Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'PHP_GCS.mp4':
>     Metadata:
>       major_brand     : mp42
>       minor_version   : 1
>       compatible_brands: mp41mp42isom
>       creation_time   : 2018-08-03T13:08:04.000000Z
>     Duration: 00:01:21.40, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1584 kb/s
>       Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1918x1078 [SAR 1:1 DAR 137:77], 1581 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc (default)
>       Metadata:
>         creation_time   : 2018-08-03T13:08:04.000000Z
>         handler_name    : Core Media Video
>
> File 'PHP_GCS.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N]

and stop the execution here until I press the enter button.I'm really confused why this is happining because when the video is already mp4 i'm not using `ffmpeg` but only for thumbnail generaton.

What can be wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you missed something in your code.

You Post handler in video converter has this code:

```
        ext = filename.split('.')
        print(ext[-1])
        only_name = ext[0]
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename)
        generate_thumbnail(filename, only_name + '_thumbnail.jpg')
        if ext == 'mp4': # mistake here
```

but you're not checking the correct part on your if statement.

You should write `if ext[-1] == 'mp4'` because right now you're comparing a list with a string which will always return false!

This might solve your problem and if not please let me know and I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: You're welcome! Please accept my answer if this has resolved your problem.